# Sharepoint automatically checking out document to user when opened

Tags: check-out, file, read-only

I'd like to start by saying I have very little sharepoint knowledge, I'm just helping out a friend ...

Basically, we have 2 users, one of which is the owner of a file on a sharepoint site (first user), and the other just wants to view the file every now and then (second user).

The problem is, is that the second user who just wants to view the file, is strangely checking the document out to him, and opening in edit mode. When this happens, it doesn't actually say in the sharepoint site that it is checked out to him, only when the first user tries to open it, and a warning is shown that it is checked out to the second user.

It is only happening on this one file.

What we want to achieve is for when the second user clicks the file, is to have it open in read-only mode.

If you require any more information, please ask :D

Answer (score 0):

I am taking a wild guess now, but you issue is most likely that User B has enough permission on the item level of that document to open it in edit mode.

So just make sure that the User does not have enough permission to edit the file, only read/view it.

Regards